# upload pdf file from local system to aws-s3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, fileapi

In my **serverless app**, I need to generate pdf dynamically and then upload that generated pdf into **aws-s3 bucket**. But in serverless, we can only sent `json` request, so I sent my html string to serverless, it generate pdf and then save that generated pdf into local machine. I think, that part I can do, But my problem is, I need to upload that newly generated pdf into **aws-s3**. My code is given below:

**Angular Code**:

```
$scope.generate_pdf = function() {

   var html = angular.element('html').html();

    var service = API.getService();   // sent html string as json for generating  pdf
    service.downloadPdf({}, { html : html },
        function(res) {
           console.log("res : ", res);  // res.url: /tmp/dynamica-generate.pdf
                                      // pdf is saved into '/tmp' folder
                                     // now I want to upload pdf from '/tmp' folder to aws-s3


       }, function(err) {
           console.log("err : ", err);
       });

};
```

How can I solve this problem, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you need to upload it from local to S3 or directly to S3 instead of local?

Comment: upload pdf from local `/tmp/some-generated-file.pdf` to S3

Comment: If you are generating the PDF file remotely via a serverless Lambda function, why not also upload it directly to S3 from there?

Comment: I already tried this, and also can upload pdf to S3, but it takes lot of time, often return error that execution time is exceeded, so I thought it may be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload file from your local machine to S3 bucket. Install [AWS Cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) on your local machine. after that is done add a cron job for this command

```
aws s3 sync /tmp/* s3://mybucket
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [aws Javascript S3 sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) to integrate JS code into your angularJS code.

You can follow from [this blog post](http://www.cheynewallace.com/uploading-to-s3-with-angularjs/) and [github code](https://github.com/cheynewallace/angular-s3-upload)

Its also mentioning about setting up the credentials using a public IAM account. Depending how you serve the files to your clients, you might check also using Pre-Signed URL’s.